# datasource datagridview tableadapter

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, tableadapter

I use vb.net to connect with the mysql.data.dll to connect to a mysql database.

In the designer of vb.net I've added the datasource, and I've added an gridview, and adjusted the gridview to have the newly added datasource as datasource.

In the load event of my form, I got this code;

```
Me.GdcTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GdcDataSet.gdc)
```

And when I fire the form, the datagridview is filled with the table from my database.

Now when I edit stuff in the datagrid view, it's not saved back into the database.

I've found an example on how to do it;

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

    if (changes != null)
    {
        MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
    }           
}
```

But the add datasource, didn't add a MySqlDataAdapter, but a TableAdapter.

So how can I write my data back to the database now?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it;

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidated

    Dim modifiedRows As gdcDataSet.gdcDataTable = CType(GdcDataSet.gdc.GetChanges(Data.DataRowState.Modified), gdcDataSet.gdcDataTable)

    If modifiedRows IsNot Nothing Then
        GdcTableAdapter.Update(modifiedRows)
        GdcDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        modifiedRows.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```